# Teleporting broken pixel on Windows 10

Tags: windows, display, dead-pixel

It is different from the other post about fake dead pixel.

The bright pixel appears randomly on the upper left of the screen.

1. It can be covered by my mouse
2. It does not appear on lockscreen or booting
3. It appears several minutes after boot-up
4. The dead pixel changes spot every time after rebooting

Right now I suspect it is a software problem but have no clue on how to fix it.

[image]
[image]
Please help!

Comment: To clarify, these are screenshots that are showing the pixel right? That would indicate that the monitor is definitely fine. Do you have a second monitor that you could plug in? It would be interesting to see if you made it the primary if the pixel would show up on that screen too.

Comment: It's probably a 1x1 pixel window. Try Process Explorer, it can find the process that shows a window. Good luck aiming! ;-)

Comment: If they appear on webpages, they can be web beacons which are very small images in webpage that track the visitors.

Comment: @Meow_ly That's exactly what I think, the pixel oddly enough don't appear on my lockscreen. It appear only after I sign in to my laptop. Sadly I don't have another monitor to experiment on it.

Comment: @WasifHasan It appears everywhere like a normal dead pixel. But I could be covered by lockscreen and my cursor.

Comment: @DanielB This looks a bit different from the 1x1 pixel window bug after I investigate a bit. Playing full screen movie or game won't cover it. I suppose it is a bit different.