# White pixel on laptop screen moves around

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, stuck-pixel

Recently, a bit after I start up my laptop, there is a white pixel that is stuck on the top left area of my screen.

When I shut my laptop down though, as it says "shutting down" the white pixel disappears. It's no longer there when I turn my laptop on again, but only for a little while. It returns eventually, but not the same spot. The only consistent thing about it is that it's always in the top left corner of my screen.

I've tried updating my gpu via geforce experience, and I've tried using jscreen to get rid of it with no luck.

It’s always only one pixel, and it moves around in that area on restart. It disappears when I’m playing a game in full screen too, but it’s still there when I exit game.

Comment: [Teleporting broken pixel on Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1561959/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That's exactly my problem, but full screen does cover it. I can't find a solution though.

Comment: This question is non-reproducible. *In the end I didn't find a proper solution, I formatted my laptop and that fixed the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

In the end I didn't find a proper solution, I formatted my laptop and that fixed the problem.